# Burnination of the 'Job' tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, tag-blacklist-request

The [job](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/job) tag should be burninated, and here is why you *should* agree!

The purpose of The Workplace is to answer difficult questions that people have about (not surprisingly) their workplace.

So therefore it stands to reason that every question that is on-topic should be, in some way, about the job that person has, or is trying to get. Be it interviewing for a job, a question about the management at your job, a question about receiving a promotion in your job, a question about changing jobs or, heaven forbid, quitting your job.

The recurring theme around all of these on topic question is that it revolves around the idea of a job, therefore isn't it right to assume that every question, by default, should have a job tag? I certainly think so, and because it would be applied to everything it really needs to be applied to nothing and just assumed its there.

Let's have a look at what we would lose by burninating this tag.

> Questions with this tag: 16
>
> Questions with this tag that are open: 7
>
> Followers of this tag: 0
>
> Tag Wiki: Empty

hmm, so we have a less than 50% open rate, no followers, and no description. This lack of description is meaning that the tag is being applied to all manner of things across the board from [speaking to employees in private in a job interview](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/11915/after-a-job-interview-is-it-inappropriate-if-i-want-to-talk-to-an-employee-in-p)  to [convincing an employer you are worth hiring despite being overqualified](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10656/is-it-okay-to-convince-a-potential-employer-to-hire-you-even-if-you-are-overqual)

**Conclusion**

So far I am yet to see a question that benefits from this tag. Nobody follows the tag, it has no description and every question that has this tag, could have it removed / replaced by a better tag with no detriment to the question.

Case closed, let the burnination begin!

*In all serious, if you think I am wrong in my judgement please don't hesitate to point it out to me, if the tag can be saved, given a good description and retroactively applied without it covering every single on topic question then please feel free to suggest it!*

Comment: [KILL IT!!! KILL IT WITH FIRE!!!](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ihN3m.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Done.

[image: Burninated]

Please care for [the widows and orphans](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/tags/untagged)!

Answer (score 0):

One reason this tag might be good, some questions here are about the process applying for a job and some are more about the actual job itself.

That being said, this distinction is so minor I don't think anyone is going to correctly apply it. I can safely say I'm not going to bother being the tag police for it, at least...

Comment: Hi @enderland, I'm thinking this is really way too broad. The following phrases come to mind:  Applying for a job, doing a job, quitting a job, researching a job, hiring for a job. That tag could lead to a lot of confusion about when to use it and when not to use it.